# Is it possible to append the data in Redis command

Tags: database, performance, redis, in-memory-database

I have 6 workload files like workloads, workloadb, workload etc.

I am using the below command to load the data.

./bin/ycsb.sh load Redis -s - P workloads/workloada -p recordcount=400000 -threads 100 dbname> outputdata.txt

As same above I will be running Run command aswell

After inserting the 400000 records then I need to append some more records

If I use the above command then the existing records getting deleted here.

How Can I append the records

I have tried with different workload file but the existing records getting deleted.

How can I append the records here